# Error : Body could not be parsed as valid XML/AMF/JSON

Tags: xml, jsp, flex4

I am calling a JSP page from Flex using an HTTP request, but I am getting an error, "Body could not be parsed as valid XML/AMF/JSON."
In the network monitor response tab I am getting the whole JSP file, which I am calling through the HTTP request. How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i also had this error but it turned out that i had different variable names and variable quantity in my Value object in flash builder compared to my mysql database after correcting this, the error went away which if you read the error a few times it does kinda make sense